# C++ Is it proper and safe to convert an array from char to unsigned int like this?

Tags: c++

**Objective:** To properly and quickly convert an array from char to unsigned int.

**Check My Work - Please:**

```
...
// NOTE:
// m_chFileBuffer is a member/variable from a class.
// m_nFileSize is also a member/variable from a class.
// iFile is declared locally as std::ifstream

// Calculate the size of iFile and copy the calculated
// value to this->m_nFileSize
iFile.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );
this->m_nFileSize = iFile.tellg( );
iFile.seekg( 0, std::ios::beg );

// Declare this->m_chFileBuffer as a new char array
this->m_chFileBuffer = new char[ this->m_nFileSize ];

// Read iFile into this->m_chFileBuffer
iFile.read( this->m_chFileBuffer, this->m_nFileSize );

// Declare a new local variable
::UINT *nFileBuffer = new ::UINT[ this->m_nFileSize ];

// Convert this->m_chFileBuffer from char to unsigned int (::UINT)
// I might be doing this horribly wrong, but at least I tried and
// will end up learning from my mistakes!
for( ::UINT nIndex = 0; nIndex != this->m_nFileSize; nIndex ++ )
{
    nFileBuffer[ nIndex ] = static_cast< ::UINT >( this->m_chFileBuffer[ nIndex ] );

    // If defined DEBUG, print the value located at nIndex within nFileBuffer
    #ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << nFileBuffer[ nIndex ] << ' ';
    #endif // DEBUG
}

// Do whatever with nFileBuffer
...

// Clean-up
delete [ ] nFileBuffer;
```

**Got Something?:**
If there is a better method to complete the objective, please post below!

**More:**
Is it possible to apply this concept to a unsigned int std::vector?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are after, but there is nothing safe about the code you show, all those raw owning pointers are liable to leak.

Comment: How can I fix this??? D:

Comment: what are the contents of the file, and what are the desired contents of the `nFileBuffer`?

Comment: @111111 I am trying to develop a new file encryption algorithm. Basically, it loads the file and analyze the decimal value of each bytes within the loaded file. Which are converted from char to unsigned int (nFileBuffer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's too much code for such a simple task, all you need is this.

```
std::vector <unsigned int> v;
std::copy (std::istream_iterator <char> (iFile), 
           std::istream_iterator <char> (), 
           std::back_inserter (v));
```

Or even shorter (thanks to @111111):

```
std::vector <unsigned int> v 
{ 
       std::istream_iterator <char> (iFile),
       std::istream_iterator <char> ()
};
```

Comment: Or better just use the std::vectors iterator constructor. `std::vector <unsigned int> v { std::istream_iterator <char> (iFile), std::istream_iterator <char> () };`

Comment: @aleguna I can't believe it was that easy! Thank you. I will accept this answer in about 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<char> buf(file_size);
/* read file to &buf[0] */
vector<unsigned int> uints(buf.size());
copy(buf.begin(), buf.end(), uints.begin());
```

Your raw new/delete-usage is not exception safe. Rule-Of-Thumb: Never write delete in your code, as long as you're not writing a destructor yourself. Also, "char" may be signed, not sure what behavior you're expecting there.

Comment: Wait, so if I locally declared an array within a block of a class function, I can delete it in the deconstructor? Are you sure? O.o

Comment: @CLearner Not sure where you got that from, but: no. Of course not. Oo

Comment: Got confused with what you read. And I know. Thanks for the info. Not sure why your post is -1, but +1 by me.

Comment: @CLearner The point is: Use the container/smart-pointer classes and let them manage your resources. Because the destructor of these object will always be called when you leave the scope, regardless of the method. (return, exception)